# remove row from the tables in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two tables and I want to remove one specific row which means that from `#tr` in `#table2` or `#tr` in `#table1`  with jquery Ajax after success

please help me

Thank you for your help.

I added also jquery code...

```html
<table id="table1">
<tbody>
<tr id="tr1"><td>row1</td></tr>
<tr id="tr2"><td>row2</td></tr>
<tr id="tr3"><td>row3</td></tr>
<tr id="tr14"><td>row4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="table2">
<tbody>
<tr id="tr1"><td>row1</td></tr>
<tr id="tr2"><td>row2</td></tr>
<tr id="tr3"><td>row3</td></tr>
<tr id="tr4"><td>row4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

   $(document).off("click", ".removeUserType").on("click", ".removeUserType", function () {
        var userTypeId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        var currentElement = $(this);
        var menuId = "<?php echo $menuId; ?>";
        var todoStatus = "remove";
        
        $.ajax({
            metod: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: {todoStatus: 'remove', userTypeId: userTypeId, menuId: menuId, removeTr: removeTr},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                notification("success");

                currentElement.closest("tr").remove(); 


            },
            error: function (err) {
                //alert("Error");                    
                notification("error");
            }

        });


    });
```

I added my js code also.

Comment: You should **not** have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Scovetta.. And I'm not quite sure how you are planning on targeting which row you'd like to remove. All of what is supposed to happen is unclear..

Comment: Sorry I wrote same id tr They should be 1,2,3,4 for each table :-(

Comment: Thank you Everyone, I made a mistake that you warn me for more than one same id in one page I fixed this and it works :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
            $(document).off("click", ".removeUserType").on("click", ".removeUserType", function () {
        var userTypeId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
        var menuId = "<?php echo $menuId; ?>";
        var todoStatus = "remove";
        $("#" + userTypeId).remove(); // THIS IS WORKING 

        $.ajax({
            metod: "POST",
            url: "page.php",
            data: {todoStatus: 'remove', userTypeId: userTypeId, menuId: menuId, removeTr: removeTr},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                notification("success");
                
                $("#" + userTypeId).remove(); // THIS IS NOT WORKING 


            },
            error: function (err) {
                //alert("Error");                    
                notification("error");
            }

        });
```

removeTr.remove(); is working outside of the ajax block but not working inside the ajax block

Answer (score 1):

You can select the Nth element using the `nth-child` selector. In the case above, you can remove those extra `id`'s from each of the `tr` element, and then just have:

```
$('#table2 tbody tr:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

This will remove the second row from the second table.

The `remove()` method is synchronous, so you can just run whatever you want to take place after it's removed on the next line.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbbry6e6/)

**Edit**

If you really want to do it with a callback, you can use `$.when`:

```
$.when($('#table2 tbody tr:nth-child(2)').remove()).then(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is `you are using same id's for multiple tr's`.

Change your code and provide a common class to all tr's and on that class name put an event listener that activates on the click and remove the current tr using `this`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve following:

HTML CODE:

```
<table id="table1">
<tbody>
<tr><td><a href="javscript;" class="remove">row1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javscript;" class="remove">row2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javscript;" class="remove">row3</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javscript;" class="remove">row4</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT CODE:

```
     $(document).on("click",".remove",function(){

                var current_element = $(this);
                var url = "your ajax url";

                jQuery.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  type:'POST',
                  success:function(data){
                      if(data == 1)/*Check success*/
                      {
                           current_element.closest("tr").remove();

                      }
                  }
                });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Sagar Arora. it works but it work both of my two tables. But i want to remove tr from one table for Example table1 not table2

Comment: @Intorka  can you please upload your ajax code so that i understand the problem?. As my code will remove always the current row whether it is table 1 or table 2